# simple 2d input in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I need to input 2d array and make changes in it but the answer is always wrong. This is my code.

```
r,c,obs = map(int, input().split())
k = []
h = []
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(h[i][j],end=" ")
    print()

while obs > 0:
    l, k = map(int, input().split())
    h[l-1][k-1] = 1
    obs -= 1

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(h[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

My input is this -

```
5 4 4
3 2
3 4
4 2
5 2
```

According to the code my resultant matrix should be something like this -

```
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

But it is always resulting to this -

```
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here??

Comment: `h.append(k)` is repeatedly appending *referrnces* to the same array to `h`, rather than independent arrays.

Comment: Hint:
`h[0] == h[1]` and `h[0] is h[1]`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot to reset `k` at the end of each iteration of the outer for-loop. How about this?

```
r,c,obs = map(int, input().split())
h = []
for i in range(r):
    k = []             # This is the only line changed.
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(h[i][j],end=" ")
    print()

while obs > 0:
    l, k = map(int, input().split())
    h[l-1][k-1] = 1
    obs -= 1

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print(h[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

The result is

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0
```

Comment: well done...! you got it stright instead of going on circles like me .. silly me :/

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for fixing my code

Answer (score 0):

**EXPLAINATION**

your way of printing is worng look at this :

```
r,c,obs = map(int, input().split())
k = []
h = []
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)
def print_arr(k1):
    for li in k1:
        for it in li:
            print(it,end=' ')
        print()
print_arr(h)
while obs > 0:
    l, k1 = map(int, input().split())
    h[l-1][k1-1] = 1
    obs -= 1
    print_arr(h)
```

input:

```
>? 5 4 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

>? 3 2
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

also because of the :

```
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)
```

what oyu do is assiging the same list to `h` and it contained the same list for c times and every change you make to any inner list it changes every column (e.g the inner lists contained)

**SOLUTION**

what would solve the issue is this, change:

```
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)
```

to:

```
for i in range(r):
    k=[]
    for j in range(c):
        k.append(0)
    h.append(k)
```

output:

```
>? 5 4 4
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
>? 3 2
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: @SAM GARAI - you did not create a 2D matrix as you will think. You could change the lines to these: (after k = []; h = [] )  And try it out.

From your original code, you just create 1D array h - that reference to the same array k. 

```python

    k = [0 for i in range(c) for i in range(r)];
    
    h = [[0 for i in range(c)] for i in range(r)]